# Unable to access Google Sheets data with Apps Script and Advanced Protection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script to process data from a Google Sheets spreadsheet. I have Google Advanced Protection enabled and it seems to be blocking my script even though I wrote it for my own data.

The [FAQ](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7539956?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccan-i-use-non-google-apps-services-or-apps-script-with-advanced-protection) says:

> If you're enrolled in Advanced Protection, Apps Script can be used. If
> scripts request access to certain data in your account, like emails,
> documents, or photos, they may be blocked.

However, I can't find any details about which functions are actually blocked or if there's any acceptable way to read my sheets data. Right now it seems like any function that tries to actually read data such as SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell or getActiveSpreadsheet prompts me for authorization (which is then blocked by advanced protection).

Is there a way around this without disabling advanced protection or will I just have to export my data and process it elsewhere?

Comment: Try disabling it and see if it works?

Comment: Just added a clarification that I don't want to disable Advanced Protection. I'm certain this would work without it, but I'm using Advanced Protection for a reason.

Comment: It is not possible to access/modify your document using apps script when advanced protection is enabled. The moment that the Sheets API is invoked the App Script will require a scoped OAuth token to edit the current spreadsheet. The Titanium OAuth policy does not allow third party applications to edit a user's documents and as such when the OAuth token is requested by the App Script the request will fail.

Comment: You may file a feature request in https://issuetracker.google.com/

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the top of your sheets app script, it'll limit the visibility to your doc and will then work.

```
/**
* @OnlyCurrentDoc
*/
```